# link speed vs throughput

Tags: throughput

I am new to networking. while doing an experiment on file transfer protocol(wired connection), I have to calculate the time taken to transfer 1 file from source to destination.
For calculating the file transfer time, i require the file size as well as the link speed.

Can anyone please explain what is this link speed and how to calculate it? 
is it same as PHY rate?

Does PHY rates exist for wired connections or it exists in wireless connections only?

And also,please explain the difference between PHY rate,link speed and throughput.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHY rate is the theoretical peak, assuming no protocol overhead, error correction or arbitration. Link speed is the same, just a different word. Throughout is then what you actually get through, limited by overhead introduced in all layers of the OSI stack. Typically further limited by latency for protocols which require round trips (e.g. TCP), data overhead from e.g. Ethernet frames or even error correction and arbitration for wireless links on the link level. For Ethernet, PHY rate and throughput are almost the same, due to a very low overhead. For transfer time you will also need latency.

Comment: you mean to say time taken to transfer 1 file = (file size/size of 1 packet)* latency ??

Comment: can we use delay in place of latency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to consider the whole protocol stack for the exercise:

- FTP
- TCP
- IP
- Ethernet
- PHY

Each of these layers reduces the raw PHY rate.

On the Ethernet and IP layers, it's quite simple. Each frame on these protocols has a maximum size (MTU) and a fixed size which needs to be allocated for the header of each frame.

After subtracting the overhead for the headers, you have the throughput via IP.

For TCP, we can ignore the data overhead for now, as the main factor is the additional round-trips added. In this case let's only deal with the handshake and ignore the other details for now. This means for the SYN-ACK-ACK sequence, we will to have account for twice the delay before the link is established from the client side.

For FTP, let's also assume the most simple case, anonymous login, active transfer, no encoding. That adds one more roundtrip before the actual data transfer starts.

Why did we choose to ignore the data size in the FTP and TCP protocol? Because for all modern link speeds, this is completely masked by the delay.

So in total your effective throughput is now `PHY rate * Ethernet overhead * IP overhead + file size / (4 * Delay)`

Choosing a different transfer encoding in FTP would add another factor to the left side. Accounting for TCP window scaling, retransmissions, login via FTP etc. would add more round-trips.

There could also be additional protocols in that stack, introducing further overhead. E.g. network tunnels.